# How to write less code when creating mouseover effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I apologize right now for the sloppy wording of this question, I'll try to explain my problem the best that I can.

Lets say I'm making a list of apples, bananas, and kiwis.  I want to create a jQuery effect where the element that my mouse is over will be underlined only while my mouse is over it, without having to write too much code if that's possible.  This is the most efficient way I currently know

```
<div id='myFavFruit'>
        <p id='apples'>apples</p>
        <p id='bananas'>bananas</p>
        <p id='kiwi'>kiwi</p>
    </div>

    $('#apples').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#apples').css("text-decoration","underline");
    });

    $('#apples').mouseleave(function() {
       $('#apples').css("text-decoration","none");
    });

    $('#bananas').mouseenter(function() {
       $('#bananas').css("text-decoration","underline");
    });

    $('#bananas').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#bananas').css("text-decoration","none);
    });

    $('#kiwi').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#kiwi').css("text-decoration","underline");
    });

    $('#kiwi').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#kiwi').css("text-decoration","none");
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check my answer below It is simplest http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370070/2006386

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to just use plain **CSS**. You can target the elements by ID or with only one line if using a class.

```
#apples:hover,
#bananas:hover,
#kiwis:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: and to use `#myFavFruit p:hover`

Comment: the question specifically mentions to use jquery

Comment: You don't need to specify the element ("p") if you are using ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Even better:

```
#myFavFruit p:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myFavFruit p')
    .mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).css("text-decoration","none");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myFavFruit'>
        <p id='apples'>apples</p>
        <p id='bananas'>bananas</p>
        <p id='kiwi'>kiwi</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that only with css like that :

```
#myFavFruit p:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Or with jQuery ([**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/49qn7eo0/))

```
$('#myFavFruit p').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).css("text-decoration","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want with jquery:

```
$('#myFavFruit p').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
});

$('#myFavFruit p').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey9k5mnu/

```
$(function () {
    var pFruit = $("#myFavFruit").find("p");
    $(pFruit).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lambo477 said, it can be done with CSS. Anyway, a shortcut for that in jQuery is to use the `.hover()` method.

Example:

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);
```

See the [jQuery documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

use pure css as it can be done without js/jquery

```css
li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>apples</li>
  <li>bananas</li>
  <li>kiwi</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add only this line that is enough

```
$("#myFavFruit").find("p").hover(function() { $(this).css("text-decoration","underline"); });
```

let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/204ckbow/) :

**HTML**

```
<div id='myFavFruit'>
<p id='apples' class="fruit">apples</p>
<p id='bananas' class="fruit">bananas</p>
<p id='kiwi' class="fruit">kiwi</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() { // DOM loaded event handler 

    // When mouse hover a fruit : apply underlying style
    $("#myFavFruit .fruit").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
    });

    // When mouse leave a fruit : removing underlying style
    $("#myFavFruit .fruit").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("text-decoration","initial");
    });

});
```

**Explaination**

I added a class to all your fruit, which let me scope both of them with a single css selector in the two function `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`.

So when you have the JQuery selector `$("#myFavFruit .fruit")`, it means **give me all the element that have the class "fruit" in my parent element "myFavFruit"**.

Comment: Why add a class when you could do without ?

Comment: Because of maintainable reasons : if tomorrow someone else modify this code and want to add another paragraph that is not a fruit, you will have an issue and will need to alter the code to prevent applying effect on this new paragraph. I have the habit to set a class to be sure to scope the element I want. But obviously there is a better way to do this without adding an additional class you are right.

Comment: I have the habit too to set classes everywhere, but here it wasn't the example asked. Just would like to say that